# Azure Sql data warehouse - is there any way to see the true query plan?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-data-warehouse

Azure SQL DWH / PDW have the `EXPLAIN` keyword to show the parallel query plan. This is really useful for seeing the data movement operations, however I was wondering if there was an equivalent of the traditional sql server query plan. I'm working on the assumption that just because there isn't any data movement, it doesn't necessarily mean that query is well optimised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditional SQL Server query plan is not available yet.  You can use `DBCC PWD_SHOWEXECUTIONPLAN` to see estimated execution plan. For actual execution plan you can get a `D-SQL` plan using Visual Studio. Grant Fritchey explains in [details](http://www.scarydba.com/2016/08/29/azure-sql-data-warehouse-execution-plans/).